# Storing encrypted text

Tags: java, encryption

I have a password vault program that uses the XOR cipher below to store usernames and passwords in a text file. Each line contains one username and password pair, and they are delimited with a comma, so it follows this format:

> username,password
>
> username,password
>
> etc.

The problem is that that the cipher will occasionally encrypt a character into a comma, so when I try to read the file again, the data will be read improperly and it will essentially be deleted.

I was thinking about solving this by checking to see if a comma results from the XOR cipher and if so, increment it to the next ascii character "-", and then return it back to a comma when reading the data and decrypting it. The problem I see with this solution is that it can cause collisions with characters that get encrypted to a "-" right away.

Can anyone think of a solution to this that I can use to prevent data from being lost?

```
    // XOR cipher
    public static String encryptDecrypt(String input, String pass) {
         char[] key = pass.toCharArray();
         StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
             output.append((char) (input.charAt(i) ^ key[i % key.length]));
         }
         return output.toString();
    }
```

Comment: The are code samples that do more heavy encryption in a regular way. `char` is UTF-16, and your xoring probably will not work, either when storing/loading, either when causing a Unicode problem (surrogate pairs). Keywords: symmetric key encryption maybe.

Comment: Even if I use another encryption algorithm that's stronger, won't I still run into this problem I'm having with the delimiter?

Comment: First, ditch your "XOR encryption" and use an actual encryption algorithm.  Second, operate on byte arrays, not strings.  Third, encode the resulting ciphertext binary into base64 encoding (which doesn't use commas).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. I don't know much about encryption, so what I exactly would I use? Would AES do the job?

Comment: AES is a great choice, yes.

Comment: For the particular problem you would normally use an escaping sequence, but XOR is definitely not the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Try DataOutputStream.writeUTF() to output the text to a file instead of storing them in a text file. Then you can use DataInputStream.readUTF() to read from the file. You don't have to delimit anything this way